# Need an example for a DetailsList in Office UI Fabric React using IColumn isFiltered Attribute

Tags: reactjs, filter, datatable, office-ui-fabric

Where can i find an example for office ui fabric react (typescript) of an IColumn isFiltered example on a details list.  The docs don't seem to have an example using isFiltered.  They just describe it in the IColumn interface and say setting it to true on a column will put a filter icon in the column header.  When I place the attribute on a column in my details list, nothing happens in the display.

Answer (score 0):

turns out we are replacing fabric assets with material design icons (mdi).  so I had to registered an mdi under the same name that the isFiltered attribute uses.

```
  Filter: <Icon path={mdiFilterMenu} style={iconStyle} color={'currentColor'} />
```

Comment: Can you share how you achieved ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I searched our current code base and it looks like we abandoned this approach, it must not have been working for us still after successfully getting the icon to appear in the header.